Estimation of model coefficients of ARIMA model
Let say I have below ARIMA model estimation in R
> arima(x = LakeHuron, order = c(0,0,1), xreg = time(LakeHuron) - 1920)

Call:
> arima(x = LakeHuron, order = c(0, 0, 1), xreg = time(LakeHuron) - 1920)

Call:
arima(x = LakeHuron, order = c(0, 0, 1), xreg = time(LakeHuron) - 1920)

Coefficients:
         ma1  intercept  time(LakeHuron) - 1920
      0.7822   579.0821                 -0.0233
s.e.  0.0651     0.1400                  0.0049

However I also calculated the model coefficients using linear regression separately for the exogenous variable and autocorrelated residuals as below
> model_lm = lm('y~x', data = data.frame(x = time(LakeHuron) - 1920, y = LakeHuron))
> model_Res = lm('y~x-1', data.frame(y = resid(model_lm), x = c(NA, resid(model_lm)[-length(LakeHuron)])))
> summary(model_lm )

Call:
lm(formula = "y~x", data = data.frame(x = time(LakeHuron) - 1920, 
    y = LakeHuron))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.50997 -0.72726  0.00083  0.74402  2.53565 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 579.088786   0.115047 5033.507  < 2e-16 ***
x            -0.024201   0.004036   -5.996 3.55e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.13 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2725,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2649 
F-statistic: 35.95 on 1 and 96 DF,  p-value: 3.545e-08

> summary(model_Res )

Call:
lm(formula = "y~x-1", data = data.frame(y = resid(model_lm), 
    x = c(NA, resid(model_lm)[-length(LakeHuron)])))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.94335 -0.48386  0.01758  0.43251  1.91083 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x  0.79084    0.06556   12.06   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7125 on 96 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.6025,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5984 
F-statistic: 145.5 on 1 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

These two approaches appear to give similar result. However I wonder if it always be the case theoretically for any data? Also which approach is better and why?
One more question I have given that I am using MA model, should I use autocorrelation adjusted SE instead normal SE in the second approach?

In arima(x = LakeHuron, order = c(0,0,1), xreg = time(LakeHuron) - 1920), you have regression with MA(1) errors, not an ARIMA model. You may want to edit your post to reflect that.

While I gave example of MA process, my question should be considered as more generic. Basically I would like to know if I estimate the coefficients in different steps like above, I would get statistically inferior estimate

OK. My point is that this is regression with ARIMA errors, not an ARIMA model. Mentioning this just to avoid unnecessary confusion. E.g. I felt a little misled by the title once I read the body.

I believe the answer is mistaken. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/ for how to interpret what arima does and why it is regression with ARMA errors rather than ARIMAX.

Thanks Richard. Everywhere I mentioned ARIMAX it should have said regression with ARMA errors. I updated my answer accordingly.

You are fitting two different models.
In the arima function, you are fitting a regression model with ARMA(0,1) errors:
$$ \begin{align*}
y_t & = \mu + \beta x_t + v_t \\
v_t &= \theta \varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t 
\end{align*} $$
With model_lm and model_Res you are fitting a regression model with ARMA(1,0) errors.
$$ \begin{align*}
y_t & = \mu + \beta x_t + v_t \\
v_t &= \phi v_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
\end{align*} $$
You can see the second model you are fitting is AR(1) (not MA(1)) by substituting for $v_t$ and $v_{t-1}$ in the second equation:
$$ \begin{align*}
y_t & = \mu + \beta x_t + v_t \\
y_t - \mu - \beta x_t &= \phi (y_{t-1} - \mu - \beta x_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t
\end{align*} $$
We can go even further, to eventually get the version of the model that can be estimated via iterative OLS (Cochrane and Orcutt, 1949) or a Bayesian version estimated via Gibbs sampling (Chib 1993). First, rearrange:
$$ \begin{align*}
y_t - \phi y_{t-1}&= \mu (1-\phi) + \beta (x_t - \phi x_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t
\end{align*} $$
Or, in matrix form:
$$ \begin{align*}
y_t - \phi y_{t-1} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1-\phi & x_t-\phi x_{t-1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}+ \varepsilon_t
\end{align*} $$
If we define $y_t^* = y_t - \phi y_{t-1}$ and $x_{t}^* = x_t - \phi x_{t-1}$, then conditional on an estimate of $\phi$, we can run the linear regression model:
$$ \begin{align*}
y_t^* &= \begin{bmatrix} 1-\phi & x_t^* \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}+ \varepsilon_t
\end{align*} $$
That is, we run a regression of $y_t^*$ on $x_t^*$ and an adjusted intercept (a column of $1-\phi$ instead of a column of ones). Then calculate the residuals (on the original scale, using $v_t = y_t - \mu - \beta x_t$), and run OLS on the residuals, $v_t$ (without intercept) to get an updated estimate of $\phi$. Finally, repeat the two regressions until convergence.
More about the Cochrane Orcutt estimator here.
In general, this iterative OLS procedure will be close to the regression model with ARMA(1,0) errors estimated by the arima function. They will not be exactly the same, since the arima function uses a maximum likelihood estimator on the nonlinear regression model $y_t = \mu + \beta x_t + \phi (y_{t-1} - \mu - \beta x_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t$

Many thanks. This is very intuitive. So the way I estimated the second model i.e. using two regression fit using lm() function appears to be incorrect because I did not use any iterative procedure that Cochrane-Orcutt Procedure does. Is it statement correct?

I'd say there are two reasons it was incorrect relative to the first model you fit. The first is that it is fitting an AR error process, while your initial model fit an MA error process. And then yes, if you want to fit an AR error process, you want to follow the iterative Cochrane-Orcutt procedure to get estimates that are close to the MLE estimates. Sometimes running one iteration like you did will be very close to MLE, but sometimes it won't.

I believe you are mistaken in your interpretation of arima. See my comments to the OP and especially this: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Apologies for getting the terminology wrong. I thought regression models with ARMA errors and ARIMAX referred to the same thing. My answer has been updated. Everything I wrote applies to regression with ARMA errors, not ARIMAX.

Please add @RichardHardy when responding to me, otherwise I do not get notified of our comments. I believe that even after your corrections, parts of the answer are mistaken. E.g. the first equation is mistaken.

@RichardHardy Thanks for the feedback, I edited the first equation accordingly. Although, it appears the ARIMAX(0,0,1) is equivalent to a regression with MA(1) in errors - to see this substitute in for $v_t$ in the top equation and you will get back my original equation

@AdamCheck, oh, indeed, this one happens to be equivalent – my bad.

In case either of  you are interested, there are equivalences between regressions with AR(1) errors and dynamic regression models. Hendry discusses it in his text "dynamic econometrics" but if you want a shorter and more to the point reference, there's a paper called "Estimating Dynamic Models is Not Merely a Matter of Technique" by Nathaniel Beck, 1985. I would have provided a link but I couldn't find a free copy.  It's on JSTOR.

When I said dynamic regression models in above, I should have said dynamic regression models with IID errors.
